# Having problems saving an object in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, crud

Maybe a trivial problem, but I looked through everything I could and couldn’t find a solution

I’m trying to save a new GeologicalClass using a post request (not the best naming, but that’s the task), but when saving it to the database, the dependent field section_id is written as null

Here is my code:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "sections")
public class Section {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    private boolean isDeleted;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "section")
    private List<GeologicalClass> geologicalClasses;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter@Setter
@Entity
@ToString(exclude = "section")
@Table(name = "geological_classes")
public class GeologicalClass {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "bigint")
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String code;
    private boolean isDeleted;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "section_id",
            insertable = false,
            nullable = false)
    private Section section;
}

@Service
public class GeologicalClassServiceImpl implements GeologicalClassService {
   @Override
    public GeologicalClass createGeologicalClass(GeologicalClass geologicalClass) {
        return geologicalClassRepository.save(geologicalClass);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/geological-classes")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GeologicalClassController {
  @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public RestResponse createGeologicalClass(@RequestBody GeologicalClass geologicalClass) {
        GeologicalClass createdGeologicalClass = geologicalClassService.createGeologicalClass(geologicalClass);
        return new RestResponse(createdGeologicalClass);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x02sT.png)

Comment: In the  request do you pass the section object ?

Comment: could you explain what you want to achieve in general? Then it could be much cleaner to understand if mapping is correct for such a task.

Comment: Vague titile. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a sequence to generate the ID. Here an example how you can apply this on you @ID field in JPA:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "table")
@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "table_id_seq",
        sequenceName = "table_id_seq",
        allocationSize = 1)
public class Table {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "table_id_seq")
    private Long id; 
}
```

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

a solution has been found. I just needed to change a couple of lines. Here is a new type of class with which everything is correctly saved to the database

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "sections")
@Where(clause = "is_deleted = false")
public class Section implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "section", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<GeologicalClass> geologicalClasses = new ArrayList<>();
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@ToString(exclude = "section_id")
@Table(name = "geological_classes")
@Where(clause = "is_deleted = false")
public class GeologicalClass implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "bigint")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "code", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "section_id",
            nullable = false)
    private Section section;
}
```